# Getting value stored in a variable in botframework suggested actions

Tags: c#, botframework

how to get the value "yes" or "no" stored into a variable? i am trying to store the value yes or no when a user clicks the button but it is not taking the value into k

```
var activity1 = MessageFactory.SuggestedActions(  
new CardAction[]
{
    new CardAction(title: "YES", type: ActionTypes.ImBack,value:"yes"),
    new CardAction( title: "NO", type: ActionTypes.ImBack, value: "no")
}, text: "Do you want to continue Shopping?");
var k=await context.SendActivityAsync(activity1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [`context.SendActivityAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.turncontext.sendactivityasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_TurnContext_SendActivityAsync_Microsoft_Bot_Schema_IActivity_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) does not return the value that the user input, it simply sends the activity without even waiting for the user to respond.

There's a couple of options to accomplish what you're looking for.

#### 1. Keep Your Code As-Is

You can keep your code mostly like it is and access the value of the user input within `OnTurnAsync()` with something like:

```
var k = turnContext.Activity.Text
```

What you do from there is up to you. The [Simple Prompt Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/04.simple-prompt/SimplePromptBot.cs) shows you how you can do this, too.

#### 2. Use a Waterfall Dialog

I'd recommend using a `ChoicePrompt`, instead of `CardAction`s.

Relevant code for you would be something like (note that this would be in addition to other necessary WaterfallDialog code):

```
private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> FirstStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
        "choicePrompt",
        new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Select an Action"),
            Choices = new List<Choice> { new Choice("Yes"), new Choice("No") },
        });
}

private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> SecondStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var k = ((FoundChoice)stepContext.Result).Value.ToString();
    return await stepContext.NextAsync();
}
```

The [Basic Bot Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.basic-bot) has very good examples of using Waterfall Dialogs.

#### Other References

- [Prompting Users for Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-primitive-prompts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)
- [Sequential Conversation Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)
- [Getting Input from Dialog Prompts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-prompts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)